# DataTip does not show value in cshtml file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, razor

After update visual studio to 15.7.0 
Data tips does not show value in cshtml file but it works in other codes

[image: cshtml file]

[image: cs file]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable Optimize code fixed[image] my problem

Answer (score 0):

From my knowledge, unless you put a breakpoint on that line in the cshtml, it has never shown the value, you can see the value in the controller because you have put the breakpoint on there.

Comment: of course I put break point on that line but it just shows the definitions

Answer (score 0):

Update to 15.7.1 will fix it. But still unstable. (sometime no show DataTip and let Chrome crash)

Answer (score 0):

as you can see when I click on quick watch it says

error CS0103: The name 'SiteName' does not exist in the current context

[image]

Comment: Did you find any solution for that? I am facing the same issue.